# How to Wait for Multiple ngResource $resource Queries to Resolve

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-promise, angular-resource

I have these ngResource queries in my controller:

```
Ages.query(function(ages){
    $scope.ages = ages;
});

Skinissues.query(function(skinissues){
    $scope.skinissues = skinissues;
});

Skintypes.query(function(skintypes){
    $scope.skintypes = skintypes;
});

Activities.query(function(activities){
    $scope.activities = activities; 
});
```

In the same controller in findOne function:

```
$scope.findOne = function() {

    Products.get({
        productId: $routeParams.productId
    }, function(product) {
        for (var i = 0; i < product.ages.length; i ++){
            for (var j = 0; j < $scope.ages.length; j ++){
                if (product.ages[i].id == $scope.ages[j].id){
                    $scope.ages[j]['ticked'] = true;
                }
            }
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < product.activities.length; i ++){
            for (var j = 0; j < $scope.activities.length; j ++){
                if (product.activities[i].id == $scope.activities[j].id){
                    $scope.activities[i]['ticked'] = true;
                }
            }
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < product.skintypes.length; i ++){
            for (var j = 0; j < $scope.skintypes.length; j ++){
                if (product.skintypes[i].id == $scope.skintypes[j].id){
                    $scope.skintypes[i]['ticked'] = true;
                }
            }
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < product.skinissues.length; i ++){
            for (var j = 0; j < $scope.skinissues.length; j ++){
                if (product.skinissues[i].id == $scope.skinissues[j].id){
                    $scope.skinissues[i]['ticked'] = true;
                }
            }
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.parents.length; i ++){
            if ($scope.parents[i].id == product.parent.id){
                $scope.parents[i]['ticked'] = true;
            }
        }
        console.log('Products', product);
        $scope.product = product;
    });

};
```

This code, sometimes, it works, sometimes it doesn't, because in the findOne function, sometimes, the `$scope.ages` `$scope.skinissues` `$scope.skintypes` or `$scope.activities` is undefined.

This happens because their queries haven't finished yet.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: If you want your findOne function to run only after all values are returned from queries then you must use promises. Not sure how you want the controller to work.

Comment: OK, when I go to route products/2, then the findOne function processes, also other resources such Ages, Activities, Skinissues also run at the same time. After the Ages, Activities, Skinissues and Skintypes finished querying, execute the callback of the Product query result.

Comment: I don't want to use promise in this case, there will be so many promise inside another promise and keep going like 4 times. It just doesn't look clean. Can I see your proposal solution please? Thanks.

Comment: What's "route products/2"?

Comment: Well when exactly do you call find one? You cannot call findOne and expect your queries to be complete if you dont use some kind of promise or a watch for all variables... All queries are asynchronous, meaning they will not stop the code when they are called. Therefore you absolutely NEED some kind of signal before actually calling your findOne function.

Comment: sorry, products/2 is a route example. it routes to the product detail page with param id 2, then findOne is executed when that route is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$q.all` to resolve the `$resource` promises.

```
angular.module('mean.variables')
.factory('Variables', function($q, Products, Ages, Activities, Skinissues, Skintypes, _){

    return {
        get: function(){
            var promiseHash = {};

            promiseHash.ages = Ages.query().$promise;
            promiseHash.skinissues = Skinissues.query().$promise;
            promiseHash.skintypes = Skintypes.query().$promise;
            promiseHash.activities = Activities.query().$promise;
            promiseHash.parents = Products.query().$promise;

            return $q.all(promiseHash);

        }
    }
});
```

The above example function returns a promise that either resolves *sucessfully* to a hash of the query objects or resolves *rejected* with the first rejected response object.

The advantage of using `$q.all()` instead of `$q.defer` is that the promise chains aren't broken and error responses are retained for clients of the factory.

From the Docs:

> The Resource instances and collections have these additional properties:
>
> - `$promise`: the promise of the original server interaction that created this instance or collection.
>
> On success, the [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) is resolved with the same resource instance or collection object, updated with data from server. This makes it easy to use in [resolve section of `$routeProvider.when()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) to defer view rendering until the resource(s) are loaded.
>
> On failure, the promise is rejected with the [http response](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) object, without the `resource` property.
>
> If an interceptor object was provided, the promise will instead be resolved with the value returned by the interceptor.

--[AngularJS ngResource API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

---

> ### all(promises);
>
> Combines multiple promises into a single promise that is resolved when all of the input promises are resolved.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> An array or hash of promises.
>
> **Returns**
>
> Returns a single promise that will be resolved with an array/hash of values, each value corresponding to the promise at the same index/key in the promises array/hash. If any of the promises is resolved with a rejection, this resulting promise will be rejected with the same rejection value.

--[AngularJS $q Service API Reference -- $q.all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all)

Comment: Never thought there is something cool like this exists. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guy, I've came up with this service by using setInterval to check if all variable are defined.

```
angular.module('mean.variables')
.factory('Variables', ['$q', 'Products', 'Ages', 'Activities', 'Skinissues', 'Skintypes', '_', function($q, Products, Ages, Activities, Skinissues, Skintypes, _){

    return {
        get: function(){
            var variables = {};
            var defer = $q.defer();
            Ages.query(function(res){
                variables.ages = res;
            });

            Skinissues.query(function(res){
                variables.skinissues = res;
            });

            Skintypes.query(function(res){
                variables.skintypes = res;
            });

            Activities.query(function(res){
                variables.activities = res; 
            });

            Products.query(function(res){
                variables.parents = res;
            });

            var timer = setInterval(function(){
                if (variables.ages && variables.activities && variables.skinissues && variables.skintypes && variables.parents){
                    defer.resolve(variables);
                    clearInterval(timer);
                }
            }, 50);

            return defer.promise;

        }
    }

}])
```